# C# TCP client received message from wrong servers

Tags: c#, tcp

I have two server with same IP but different ports:
(a) Server A - 192.0.0.161:8800
(b) Server B - 192.0.0.161:8801

At the same time, I have two client instances (Client A & Client B) that will connect to each server. In other words, Client A will connect to Server A, while Client B will connect to Server B. In ideal case, when Server A broadcast message (Msg A), only Client A shall receive the message only. However, I face problem that Client A and Client B received message from Server A when Server A and Server B broadcast message at the same time. Any idea of this problem?

Comment: Maybe show what you do when you say broadcast. I don't get tcp and broadcast that well together.

Comment: Show code that reproduces the problem

Comment: This is a confused situation that is impossible to understand without you doing work to present us an example we can run.